# Shorten a Python regular expression pattern

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I import `re` and used the below `re.compile(pattern)`,

`pattern = re.compile('\d+\.\d+\s+[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+\s+\d+(?:\,\d+)?,\d+\s+[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+')`

to obtain a list from a string,

```
['2.2 based on 1,135,421 player feedback', 
 '6.0 based on 5,135,421 player feedback', 
 '9.9 based on 421 player feedback', 
 '2.2 based on 135,421 player feedback']
```

How could I shorten the pattern in the `re.compile` to obtain a same result?

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to know what to suggest, unless you first tell us the acceptance criteria. You've shown 4 things that you want to match, but what **don't** you want to match? I'll provide my best guess as an answer below, but if it doesn't meet your needs then you'll need to be more specific in the question.

Comment: There are two `\d+\s+[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+` in your pattern. Thus, `x=r'\d+(?:\s+[a-z]+){2}'` and then `pattern = re.compile(rf'\d+\.{x}\s+\d+(?:\,\d+)?,{x}')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided, this is what I would suggest using to make the pattern matching much simpler and more transparent:

```
re.compile('\d{1,2}\.\d based on \d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})* player feedback')
```

This assumes your sentence will be a specific structure, rather than fuzzy-matching "spaces and letters" - which could match against all sorts of things. It's better to be explicit, if possible.

I've also assumed that the first number will always contain exactly two or three digits - like `2.2`, `6.0`, `9.9`, or (presumably) `10.0`.

And I've also assumed that the second number will contain 1-3 digits, possibly followed by zero-or-more groups of commas and 3 more digits - like `1,135,421`, `13,421` or `421`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what inputs you might have, you can reduce the boundaries, with some expression similar to:

```
\.?\d*(?:\.\d*)?\sbased on.+?feedback\b
```

based on what you'd define a valid number.

#### Test

```
import re

expression = r"\.?\d*(?:\.\d*)?\sbased on.+?feedback\b"


string = """
some words there 2.2 based on 1,135,421 player feedback some words here 
6.0 based on 5,135,421 player feedback some words 
here 9.9 based on 421 player feedback some words here 
2.2 based on 135,421 player feedback some words here 
some words there 2 based on 1,135,421 player 
feedback some words here 6. based on 5,135,421 player 
feedback some words here 9.9 based on 421 player feedback some 
words here .1 based on 135,421 player feedback some words here 

"""

print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
['2.2 based on 1,135,421 player feedback', '6.0 based on 5,135,421 player feedback', '9.9 based on 421 player feedback', '2.2 based on 135,421 player feedback', '9.9 based on 421 player feedback', '.1 based on 135,421 player feedback']
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/09S1zs/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/09S1zs/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty clear, assuming those four examples are representative of the data set as a whole.

```
re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+ based on [\d\,]+ player feedback')
```

I would guess you also are looking to use the parsed numbers as well. Capture groups and a little post-processing can accomplish this.

```
re_feedback = re.compile(r'(\d+\.\d+) based on ([\d\,]+) player feedback')
m = re_feedback.match('2.2 based on 1,135,421 player feedback')
score_str, n_players_str = m.groups()
score = float(score_str)
n_players = int(n_players_str.replace(',', ''))

score => 2.2
n_players => 1135421
```